# InsrumentationTestRunner onException() not called

Tags: android, automated-tests

There's an `onException()` method in the `InstrumentationTestRunner` class that should be called whenever an application being tested crashes because of an unhanded exception.

For some reason, `onException()` is not called when an application crash is caused by code that executes in the `onReceive()` method of a `BroadcastReceiver` that is receiving a broadcast from a `LocalBroadcastManager`.

In other words, if I call:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_CRASH);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance().registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInsance().sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_CRASH));
```

then the code in the following `onReceive()` method will not result in a call to `onException()`:

```
public void onReceive() 
{

Object nullPointerCauser = null;
nullPointerCauser.toString();   

}
```

If, on the other hand, the `BroadcastReceiver` gets a broadcast from a call to `sendBroadcast()`, `onException()` will be called. If I call:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_CRASH);
Activity.this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
Activity.this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_CRASH));
```

then

```
public void onReceive() 
{

Object nullPointerCauser = null;
nullPointerCauser.toString();   

}
```

will cause the application to crash and `onException()` will be called in the `InstrumentationTestRunner`

Anyone ever have a problem like this? Any idea what might cause this? Any ideas for solutions?